# Sharepoint Hybrid authentication for dynamics 365 on-premise version

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-integration

We are trying to integrate Dynamics 365 CRM on-premise with SharePoint online .On Second steps of Server-Based SharePoint integration it is asking for configuration of sharepoint sites for Hybrid authentication . 
[image]

If yes , Hybrid sharepoint configuration is not showing any option to connect with on-premise Dynamics CRM.